# iOS 11 | CSS: Background render issue

Tags: ios, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, ios11

I have a "menu container" which in this case is:
`<div class="c-navbar__bottom"></div>`

This "menu container" has the following properties:

```
background: #096538;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
```

This "menu container" has a height of `0px` whenever the content of the "menu container" is being hidden. Its using the Bootstrap mobile menu trigger(with classes such as `"collapse navbar-collapse"`).

**Now to the problem:**
One of our developers used `position: absolute;` on the "menu container". In iOS 11 in combination with Safari the `background: #096538;` is not being rendered upon expanding the content of "menu container". It works once I use `position: relative;`

**I would like to know why it is not being rendered upon using: `position: absolute;`**